# Wordpress redirect all .php files except core wordpress files

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've recently moved an old site from an old cms system to wordpress. The old site used .php file extensions for posts (ie. wesbitename.com/postname.php). When I  moved the site to wordpress I tried to redirect all old links with .php extensions to extension-less posts. (wesbitename.com/postname.php redirects to wesbitename.com/postname). Here is the code I used in the htaccess file.

```
# redirect to .php-less link if requested directly
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s.+\.php\sHTTP/.+
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php $1 [R=301,L]
```

However this is an issue because the wordpress core files in wp-admin/ all redirect to extension-less urls which doesn't allow users to login and do anything. Big issue.

Is there a htaccess code snippet that only redirects Wordpress POSTS that are linked to with .php extensions and NOT the entire wordpress and website directory with .php file extensions?

My site has 10,000 posts so putting individual redirects for each page isn't doable.

I'd like to redirect all links that have .php extensions EXCEPT files inside wordpress core folders like "wp-admin" "wp-content" etc

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule !^wp- %1 [R=301,L,NC]
```